# Benchmark postgresql cluster (postgres-xc) using Daabase Test tool-2 (DBT2)

Tags: database, postgresql, postgres-xc

I'm trying to understand benchmark tool DBT2. I want to benchmark on postgres-xc, i could not get much information about how to set up the environment of postgres-xc for DBT2. I have got the DBT2 from the [link](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=52479&package_id=54389)

I have fixed some compilation issues. But i have not much idea on how to use this tool. Please provide some insights. I'm completely new o this.  thanks!!

Comment: There's not much people can do to help without more detail to what your problem is.

Comment: I just want to run DBT2 on postgres-xc, I have tried searching, but i could not get much information. All i want to know is how to setup the postgres-xc cluster. I have tried with starting GTM, 1 coordinator and 2 datanodes. But when i start 'run_workload' script, server gets stopped and never starts again. Please Help..

Comment: Assuming you've read everything linked from here: http://postgresxc.wikia.com/wiki/Postgres-XC_Wiki then I would recommend the postgres-xc mailing lists.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure of how to use DBT-2, I would focus on just using it against PostgreSQL itself.

Once you are more familiar with it, you can try DBT-2. I have only run DBT-1 and DBT-3 against Postgres-XC and Postgres-XL.

Note that the DBT-1 version used in testing XC has the schema partitioned a certain way to reduce the amount of implicit two phase commits that you need to do.  I have not looked at DBT-2, but you should select the hash distribution column carefully (CREATE TABLE .... DISTRIBUTE BY HASH(some_column)).  Also, for tables that are fairly static, please add DISTRIBUTE BY REPLICATION to the CREATE TABLE statements.

If you do end up testing Postgres-XC or Postgres-XL, I would love to hear about your results.